# How do I get a UITableView' cell's data?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I need to get part of the selected row's data (cell.textLabel.text).  The problem is this is what is in the cell (according to the debugger) and I can't figure out how to get to it.  This is the line of code in -didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
NSString *cellText = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
```

and this is what's in *selectedCell.textLabel.text*:

[image]

For the life of me, I can't figure out *how* to get the 1st of the 3 parts.

Any ideas/comments/answers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You shouldn't ever need to get data out of a view. Your view is there to display data not store it. If you want to get the text in that view then just go to the array of data (or whatever) that you used to populate it in the first place.

Comment: You don't understand the issue; I agree with you up to a point, but sometimes one has to use unconventional methods to get an issue solved.  Thank you for the comment tho'  SD

Comment: How are you creating and configuring your cells?  IOW, what does your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work; this is the code:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {

if(isFiltered)  {
    Books *su = filteredTableData[indexPath.row];
    passedSKU = su.sku;
}
else {
    //  get the key from the cell that was selected from the list
    Books *selectedBook = [booksArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    passedSKU = selectedBook.sku;
}

//  programmatically set the tabBar index
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex: 1];
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this?

```
NSString *cellText = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
NSArray *components = [cellText componentsSeparatedByString:@"  "];
if (components.count > 0) {
    NSString *firstPart = components[0];
    NSLog(@"%@", firstPart);
}
```

Comment: Interesting... nothing gets into *cellText* and I don't know why, because *selectedCell.textLabel.text* has a value in it.  Thanks for trying... I appreciate it.  SD